# Why a function of python class is called twice

Tags: python, spyder

I am having a problem with the function of python class that is called twice.
I am using Spyder IDE.

Here is my simple code

```
class Test:
    def f(self):
        print("a")


from Test import *
t = Test()
t.f()
```

When I press "Run File" button...the result is

```
a
a
```

But when I try to highlight everything and press "Run Cell"...the result is

```
a
```

I would like to know what happen when I press "Run File" and how to solve this issue.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you should import **modules**, not classes. So when you are doing `from Test import *` you are running all your code, which includes the instantiation and call to the `f` method. And after importing you are instantiating and calling it again, so that's the reason it is being printed twice, because it is being run twice.